# How can you automate terminal commands?

Tags: python, linux, macos, shell, ssh

I'm tired of doing this.

```
ssh me@somehost.com
input my password
sudo su - someuser
input my password
cd /some/working/directory
<run some commands>
```

Is there anyway to automate this? Do I need a special shell? or a shell emulator? can I programmatically drive the shell up to certain point then **run manual commands on it**?

Bonus points of it's programmed in python for extra hacking goodness

edit: All the answers below focus on the "full automation" part of the question: Where the hard part is what I highlighted above. Here is another example to see if I can capture the essence.

```
ssh me@somehost.com
<get a shell because keys are setup>
sudo su - user_that_deploys_the_app
<input password, because we don't want to give passwordless sudo to developers>
cd env; source bin/activate
cd /path/where/ur/app/is/staging
<edit some files, restart the server, edit some more, check the logs, etc.>
exit the term
```

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What terminal commands? For which OS? What kind of automations? Use cases?

Comment: I'd definitely try something involving sweet Japanese robots.

Comment: offtopic - move to serverfault

Comment: @CarlosZ the starting os will be mac and the target anything you can ssh into it. The usecase is to stop repeating things and the type of automatization will be go to this box and do this, then to another and do that.

Answer (score 2):

For the ssh/authentication piece, you can [setup passwordless authentication by using keys](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm).  Then you can simply use `ssh` and a bash script to execute a series of commands in an automated fashion.

You **could** use Python here, but if you are executing a series of shell commands, it's probably a better idea to use a shell script, as that's precisely what they do.

Alternately, look into [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) for your automation needs.  It's Python-based, and your "recipes" are written in Python.

Comment: `-c` flag is used for: *"Selects the cipher specification for encrypting the session."* according to the ssh manpage ... You don't need any flag or option, just use `ssh myhost "command"` ... See ssh(1)...

Comment: @Carpet yeah I just realized I was confusing that with `sh -c` and you don't need an argument at all, edited out

Comment: Yeah, it can get confusing sometimes :)

Comment: You can't stop in the middle of a fabric script to run some manual commands then continue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but what you're probably asking about is getting SSH working in password-less mode using public keys. The general idea is you generate an SSH keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

which gives you `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. You append the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of your target user, and SSH from that point on will not ask for credentials. In your example, this will work out to:

**Only once**

```
# On your source machine
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
# Copy this to clip board

# On somehost.com
su - someuser
# edit ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and paste what you had copied from previous step
```

From now on, you can now just run

```
ssh someuser@somehost.com "sh -c 'cd /some/dir; command.sh'"
```

and not be prompted for credentials.

Comment: passwordless SSH will remove only part of the problem. How can you automate running commands once you are on the server? What if what you want to do is setup some env flags then cd into a directory and then "look around" ie: edit a file restart a server edit another file restart again, etc.

Comment: Wrap those commands in a shell script and execute that script via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

fabric is a fine choice, as others have pointed out.  there is also [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) which might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Fabric as well as Paramiko. Currently do not have interactivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `autoexpect`. It creates `expect` script (script language intended to handle interaction with user). Run

```
autoexpect ssh me@somehost.com
```

followed by rest of commands. Script `script.exp` will be created. 
Please note, that exact results of input and output will be recorded by the script. If output may differ from execution to execution, you'll need to modify a bit generated script.

Comment: this looks interesting. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out you need to have a secure way of doing ssh and sudo on the boxes. Those items are universal to dealing with linux/unix boxes. Once you've tackled that you can use [fabric](http://fabfile.org). It's a python based tool to do automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set stuff up in your `~/.ssh/config`
For example:

```
Host somehost
    User test
```

See ssh_config(5) for more info.

Next, you can generate a SSH key using ssh-keygen(1), run ssh-agent(1), and use that for authentication.

If you want to run a command on a remote machine, you can just use something like:

`$ ssh somehost "sh myscript.sh ${myparameter}"`.

I hope this at least points you in the right direction :)

If you *need* sudo access, then there are obvious potential security issues though ... You can use `ChrootDirectory` on a per user basis inside a `Match` block though. See sshd_config(5) for info.

Comment: See my answer to the two above that suggest the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try module [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). This can meet your requirement.

Comment: as far as I know Paramiko lacks the interactivity that I need. It normally drives the whole execution of the program.